# Executing stored procedure does not work with adding parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL I have an exec like this:

```
    EXEC [dbo].[usp_TaskStatus_Time_Calculation_Final] 
       @EmployeeGuidIdTableType = @EmployeeGuidIdTableType, 
       @StartingDate = '2018-08-02 00:00:00.000', 
       @EndingDate = '2018-08-08 00:00:00.000'
```

It works correctly, parameters do their job correctly, so I want to reproduce this in C# and I do:

```
public DataTable ExeSQLParamAndType(string SprocName, DataTable paramArray, string tableTypeName, string parameters = null)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SprocName, this.dbconn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(tableTypeName, SqlDbType.Structured));
    cmd.Parameters[tableTypeName].Value = paramArray;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameters, SqlDbType.NVarChar));

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Table1")
        {
            Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        };
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    try
    {
        da.Fill(tbl);
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetTableBySQL", SprocName);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

    return tbl;
}
```

Execute method:

```
db.ExeSQLParamAndType("StoredProcedureCalc", parameters,
                      "@EmployeeGuidIdTableType",
                      $"@StartingDate = '{startDate}', @EndingDate = '{endDate}'");
```

I get an exception when trying to pass `StaringDate` and `EndingDate` parameter in line  `this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetTableBySQL", SprocName);`

> @StartingDate = ''2018-08-02 00:00:00.000'', @EndingDate = ''2018-08-08 00:00:00.000'' is not a parameter for procedure StoredProcedureCalc

Someone see something wrong there? Regards

**Note**: If I execute it from c# without this two parameters (just with table type) it works

**Update**

I change my code as comments below to:

```
var startDate =  $"'{startingDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000")}'";
var endDate = $"'{endingDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000")}'";

db.ExeSQLParamAndType("usp_TaskStatus_Time_Calculation_Final", parameters, "@EmployeeGuidIdTableType", startDate, endDate);
```

and method like:

```
public DataTable ExeSQLParamAndType(string sprocName, DataTable paramArray, string tableTypeName, string startingDate, string endingDate)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocName, this.dbconn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(tableTypeName, SqlDbType.Structured));
    cmd.Parameters[tableTypeName].Value = paramArray;

    DateTime.TryParse(startingDate, out var startDate);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    cmd.Parameters["@StartingDate"].Value = startDate;

    DateTime.TryParse(startingDate, out var endDate);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    cmd.Parameters["@EndingDate"].Value = endDate;

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Table1")
            {
                Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            };

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    try
    {
        da.Fill(tbl);
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetTableBySQL", sprocName);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

    return tbl;
}
```

But I have troubles with `DateTime`, how can I parse as desire output format: 2018-08-02 00:00:00.000 ?

Comment: Have you tried with [Dapper?](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/835519/passing-table-valued-parameters-with-dapper)

Comment: No sir, I'm updating really old windows forms project so I think that's no a solution @gbjbaanb

Comment: have you tried with Dapper... its a SQL client library so will work quite happily with winforms and any other C# app.

Comment: @Pepe No one can read your mind or see your screen. Your topic still refers to "does not work" which was a runtime error initially. Does the procedure now execute successfully? What does "how can i part as desire output ..." mean? Are you now having a display issue with the information returned by the procedure? And please think about your error handling. Is the label "GetTableBySQL" useful to anyone? It does not appear you have a method or function of that name.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is caused because

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameters, SqlDbType.NVarChar));
```

is creating a parameter with the name of whatever value is held in the variable `parameters` which is the string value `"@StartingDate = '{startDate}', @EndingDate = '{endDate}'"` because that is what you passed into `ExeSQLParamAndType` with this code:

```
db.ExeSQLParamAndType("StoredProcedureCalc"
, parameters
, "@EmployeeGuidIdTableType"
,$"@StartingDate = '{startDate}', @EndingDate = '{endDate}'");
```

you need to create two parameters, one called `startDate` and one called `EndDate`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(startingDate, SqlDbType.NVarChar));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(EndingDate , SqlDbType.NVarChar));
```

Comment: He probably wants `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2018, 8, 8)` and such.

Comment: exactly <br /><br />

Comment: Exactly, I have problems with date, I update my try in my question with current issue there

Answer (score 0):

C# DateTime and SQL Server DateTime are incompatible. You must change the setting in your SQL tables to use Datetime2 not DateTime.  You can do this by directly issuing an ALTER statement to every table with a Datetime field in your Database or adding a one line command in your DbContext class telling Entity Framework to specifically use "datetime2" for all classes that use DateTime.